# Python/PySpark spacy return array instead of single string

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying using spacy to tokenize a text and want to turn the string of tokens into an array. Currently using:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def spacy_tokenizer(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    return [token.text for token in doc]
tokenize = udf(spacy_tokenizer)

df2 = df.withColumn('TOKEN', tokenize('SENTENCE'))

from pyspark.sql.functions import array
df3 = df2.withColumn("TOKEN_ARRAY", array('TOKEN'))
df3.show()
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|  SENTENCE     |  TOKEN              | TOKEN_ARRAY           |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|  Cool to wear.|  [Cool, to, wear, .]| [[Cool, to, wear, .]] |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

It is making an array with one element that is the full string, where as I want an array with 4 elements (with each individual token as an element).
Tested this by using array contains which only shows true when I search the entire string and shows false when I search for an individual token.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_contains
df4=df3.withColumn("test", array_contains("TOKEN_ARRAY", "[Cool, to, wear, .]")).show()
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------+
|  SENTENCE     |  TOKEN              | TOKEN_ARRAY           | test  |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------+
|  Cool to wear.|  [Cool, to, wear, .]| [[Cool, to, wear, .]] | true  |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------+


df4=df3.withColumn("test", array_contains("TOKEN_ARRAY", "Cool")).show()
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------+
|  SENTENCE     |  TOKEN              | TOKEN_ARRAY           | test  |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------+
|  Cool to wear.|  [Cool, to, wear, .]| [[Cool, to, wear, .]] | false |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------+
```

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47682927/how-to-create-a-udf-in-pyspark-which-returns-an-array-of-strings

Answer (score 1):

Needed to specify array type this way and then it worked.

```
tokenize = udf(spacy_tokenizer, ArrayType(StringType()))
```